# Correct Vue application skeleton

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, vue.js

I am very new to vue and I have followed some guideline to use it.
In the first, that is [here](https://medium.com/coding-vault/starter-template-for-a-mevn-mongodb-expressjs-vuejs-v2-nodejs-stack-application-part-1-62820aeb2a06) the project was structure in this way:
1) There is a src directory, and inside I have : assets,components,route,services and view.
2) There is also a server directory and inside I have : src and models directory.

But, In another guide, [this one](https://www.vuemastery.com/courses/real-world-vue-js/vue-cli/)  I found this skeleton:
1) There is only a src directory.

Which is the best way and Why is better to use one of this structure?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way is for you to create a project with [Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/), which will end up creating the structure you mentioned first.

In a very simple project you can put all just into a simple *src* directory, but that is off topic here on Stackoverflow, because it is an opinion; there is no such thing as a single correct directory structure.

Answer (score 1):

Don't get hung up on this. If you are new, and you're not aware of having special requirements, start with the templates in vue cli. They are a good common standard. If/when you want to branch out, do so for a reason. [Here are some good project templates](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2018/04/23/vue-boilerplate-template-scaffold/) with various specialisations (enterprise, OAuth, etc)

Comment: Thank you, very interesting boilerplate inside the link